# How access SharedPreferences in another activity ?

Tags: android

I have SharedPreferences in main activity like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

public void showUserSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Editor editor= sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("userFormat", sharedPrefs.getString("example_list", "2"));
    editor.commit();    
}
```

now I wanna get value from SharedPreferences but in bellow class :

```
public class ReadFormatSharePerf extends Activity {
private DecimalFormat df;
public String finalFormat(String finalFormat) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String customFormat = sharedPrefs.getString("userFormat", "#.##");
    df = new DecimalFormat(customFormat);
    String result = df.format(finalFormat);
    return result;      
}
```

I called above activity like this code :

```
public class Angles  {
 ...

 ...
ReadFormatSharePerf my= new ReadFormatSharePerf();
    result=my.finalFormat(String.valueOf(finalValue));
}
```

I caught error :

```
10-16 15:57:24.035: E/AndroidRuntime(10792): java.lang.NullPointerException

atandroid.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
```

how I can do it  ?

Comment: please also post your ContextWrapper.java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should not be instantiating your `Activity` objects with `new`. Instead, either make the class not inherit from `Activity`, or instantiate it via `Intent`.
2. The NPE comes from trying to use an `Activity` as a `Context` before its `onCreate()` i.e. in a constructor or a member variable initializer. If you're using the `Intent`-based instantation, move the code that requires a `Context` to `onCreate()` or later in the activity lifecycle. If you make the class not an `Activity`, pass in a `Context` reference from caller.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, do:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will help you and Shared Preference **KEY** values must be same

**Saving the values**

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();    
        editor.putInt(String.valueOf(key), value);//store int values, can use string,arrays,etc 
        editor.commit();
```

Try to use **this**

**Load the saved values**

```
 SharedPreferences getProgramPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        int Index = getProgramPrefs.getInt(String.valueOf(key), -1);
```